# Using latex for Killer Chess Training homework club?

Tags: learning, diagram

Killer chess training gives out worksheets like https://p8e5c7t2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Friendly-Homework-23-%E2%80%93-2021-03-23.pdf every week.

They ask students to do three things:

1. Mark weaknesses with green squares (alternate: mark with circle)
2. Mark the worst placed piece(s) on both sides with yellow squares (alternate: mark with square)
3. Indicate the opponent’s idea with red arrows

Is there a latex package for marking up chess diagrams in this way?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple latex packages to produce chess boards (diagrams)
most comprehensive is [chessboard](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard?lang=en) by Ulrike Fischer with numerous options (but it doesn't work with RTL languages).
Start from there, everything you've described is in that package.
if not satisfied try [mpchess](https://ctan.org/pkg/mpchess) (works fine with RTL languages)
Browse the documentation first the illustrations will show you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [`xskak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak?lang=en) package which loads and extends the [`skak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/skak?lang=en) package while also loading the [`chessboard`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard?lang=en) package.

Overleaf has a [great tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chess_notation) with examples, as well as links to examples in the documentation for the referenced packages. Works with both FEN and PGN notation.

Replacing `\showboard` with `\chessboard` will add a marker to the right of the diagram indicating if it is White to move or Black to move. Turn this off with `\chessboard[showmover=false]`.

**Additional features:**

- Highlight squares in color: See code below and also this answer, [Chess Notation with skak: How to highlight squares?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215334/169506)
- Drawing colored squares and circles on specific coordinates along with colored arrows is also possible according to the documentation (see documentation dated 23 June 2019, Sections 5.4–5.5, pages 30–34). See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170056/169506).
- Create nonstandard boards (e.g. 4 x 16): [Different chess board using skak package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358041/169506)

#### Example using [`xskak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak?lang=en):

Be sure to include `\usepackage{xskak}` in the preamble.

```
% Example (works with both skak and xskak packages)
% Preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in},margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xskak}

% Document
\begin{document}

Figure~\ref{fig:startpos} shows the starting position.

\begin{figure}[h!]   % example use with figure
    \centering
    \newgame
    \chessboard % instead of \showboard
    \caption{Starting position for a game of chess.}
    \label{fig:startpos}
\end{figure}

For example White may choose to lead with the King's pawn fighting for central squares with \mainline{1. e4}.  

Black responds with \mainline{1...e5} also seeking to grab central space.

Play proceeds with \mainline{2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5}.

\begin{center}
    \chessboard  % no need for LaTeX figure 
\end{center}

% Showcase use of FEN
\newpage
\section*{Mate in 2}
\noindent Notes:  White to move. 

\section*{Galitsky A}
\newgame
\fenboard{6R1/2pk4/8/8/4QK2/8/8/8 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard

\section*{Kolodnas Z}
\newgame
\fenboard{8/4P1Q1/3k4/8/3K4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[showmover=false]  % remove move indicator

\newpage
% Position source: https://lichess.org/wFLCholu
\chessboard[setfen=2rq1r1k/pb3pp1/1p6/b2PP3/3pB3/P7/1PQ2PPP/R1B2RK1 w - - 0 18,
            pgfstyle=border,
            markfields={h7,a5},
            color=blue!50,
            colorbackfield=b2,
            pgfstyle=color,
            opacity=0.5,
            color=red,
            markfield={a5},
            color=green,
            markfield={c2}]
\end{document}
```

#### Output:

[image: Example xskak package output using LaTeX code.]

[image: Example xskak package output using LaTeX code.]

[image]